# Odd behaviour with mysql function in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a small function which queries the database and returns the primary key ID of the identified record.  When this is run on its own, everything is fine.

For example:

`SELECT fn_identify_required_user('RF24T','20180510');`

returns in 0.02 secs with a single INT value.  Lets say that with the two variables, the SELECT returns value 977.

**FUNCTION CLARIFICATION**
The function is a seeks to identify the user record from the details specified, and identifier and date of joining.  It does this by using an involved SELECT statement (which includes two other nested SELECT queries) then orders by a specific field and has a LIMIT of 1, so that we only ever return one record ID value.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxx`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_identify_required_user`(
    vIdentifier CHAR(6),
    vCalendarId BIGINT
) RETURNS bigint(20)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
```

Within MySQL there is a stored procedure (just starting to develop this) I have a single Select statement:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users as u
WHERE u.userid = 977
```

This runs in 0.01 seconds and returns the name of the user.

However

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users as u
WHERE u.userid = fn_identify_required_user('RF24T','20180510');
```

Just hangs and times out the MySQL server after 15 seconds.  I must be missing something, but when run as two separate queries, manually putting the returned value from the function into the WHERE statement, its fast and works.  Put the function in to return that value automatically and it falls apart.

I will add, I have tried with different variables into the function and proven that there is no problem with this specific recordset.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction or identify what has gone wrong?**  Because of business reasons, I cannot include the full details of the Function, needless to say the fact that it runs fine in a SELECT statement shows there are no errors.

Comment: If you can't show your real function, show some altered function (that still demonstrates the problem)

Comment: Show function's characteristics (from the beginning till BEGIN keyword). Is it defined as DETERMINISTIC?

Comment: @ysth I don't think the function is the issue, because when it is run independently it is fine, the problem is when the function is put into the WHERE statement.  That is the bit I do not understand, but I will try and clarify a bit more about the function in the description above.

Comment: @Atkina - it is defined as DETERMINISTIC

Comment: @Atkina - have just tried the function it as NON-DETERMINISTIC and had the same results. Works fine when called in a SELECT (returns in < 0.1 second) but times out MYSQL after 15 seconds when included in a WHERE.

Comment: if you don't think the function is the problem, it should be easy to come up with some other function that still demonstrates the problem